# Sum of Arithmetic-Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

So I am having trouble getting the sum of the series:

$1 + 2\left(\frac32\right) + 3\left(\frac{3^2}{2^2}\right) + ... + k\left(\frac{3^{k-1}}{2^{k-1}}\right)$

I cant figure out for the life of me how to figure out the sum of this.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Sum_to_infinite_terms OR http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Arithmetico-geometric_series#Infinite_Sum

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let
$$
S = 1+a+a^2+\cdots + a^k = {1-a^{k+1}\over 1-a}
$$
Differentiating for $a$ we get
$$
S^\prime = 1 + 2a + 3a^2 + \cdots + ka^{k-1} = {a^k(ka-k-1)+1\over (a-1)^2}
$$
It is then obvious that for $a={3\over 2}$ we get the wanted sum, that is
$$
1+2\bigl({3\over 2}\bigr) + \cdots + k\bigl({3\over 2}\bigr)^{k-1}=\bigl({3\over 2}\bigr)^k(2k-4)+4
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}{i \cdot \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{(i-1)}}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}{\sum\limits_{j=i}^{k-1}{{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}^j}}$$
$$=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}{\frac{ \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^i -\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k}{1-\frac{3}{2}}}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1- \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k }{ 1-\frac{3}{2}}-k\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) ^k}{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$=(2k-4)\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k+4$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k a^{k-1} = \frac{d}{da}\sum_{k=1}^n a^k = \dfrac{d}{da}\left(\sum_{k=0}^na^k -1\right)
$$